# Random problem when generating PDF in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have a problem in production when I generate pdf through renderPdf. Sporadically when it will render the error in some MAP property that I send to the GSP, for example:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'diario' on null object

However, when you try again with the same data, the pdf is successfully generated. I use the Grails version 3.3.2.

Comment: It looks like there is code somewhere in your app that is referencing a property named `diario` on a `null` reference, which isn't allowed.  It would be very difficult to guess what is wrong without seeing the code or a sample app that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Hey Felipe, be warned that the Grails 3 community plugins are being booted from bintray/jcenter in 1 month when bintray closes for good ... so anything you have that relys on those artefact repos you may also want to load locally or else you might have breaking changes further down the road as well.

Comment: Felipe you do not need to load any plugins locally.  The build system will continue to resolve dependencies at build time, and I don't think any of that will have anything to do with the `NullPointerException` question you asked.

Answer (score 0):

I increased the RAM memory in the Grails configuration and decreased the occurrence of this error.

```
export GRAILS_OPTS="-XX:PermSize=2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m"
```